# Javascript RegEx failing (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to add emoticons to my web-based chat site, and trying to use RegExp to do it.

It works under some circumstances, but not others, and it's driving me crazy.

The emoticons are stored in a database - I pull them out via AJAX json and work through the resulting array, replacing as it goes.  Here's what the response looks like via the F12 Dev tools :

[image: arrayVisual]

When the emoticon.SymbolShortcut value is set to ':D', it works, but does not work for ':('.

The problematic emoticon object contains :

**emoticon.FileLocation** = `'<i class="material-icons emoticon" style="font-size:16x;">sentiment_very_satisfied</i>'` //I know this isn't a file location - bad object naming :)

**emoticon.SymbolShortcut** = ':('

```
var sMarkup;
var strRegEx = '';

var pText ='some text :('

$.each(emoticonArray, function (index, emoticon) {
    strRegEx = emoticon.SymbolShortcut.replace(')', '[)]').replace('(', '[(]');

    var regEx = new RegExp(strRegEx, "gi");

    pText = pText.replace(strRegEx, emoticon.FileLocation);

});
```

So in summary, the issue is the replace doesn't work for the ':(' char combination, but does work with ':D'.

I expect the characters in the pText variable ':(' to be replaced with 'sentiment_very_satisfied', but all I get back is the same string I handed in, with no replacement made

Thanks in advance - all and any suggestions are welcomed.  Please shoutout if I can provide any more information to get this most frustrating puzzle solved.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? "Failing", "doesn't work" are not helpful. How does that work? What do you expect? Please provide an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Wiktor, The issue is the replace doesn't work for the ':(' char combination, but does work with ':D'.  I expect the characters in the pText variable  ':(' to be replaced with '<i class="material-icons emoticon" style="font-size:16x;">sentiment_very_satisfied</i>', but all I get back is the same string I handed in, with no replacement made.

Comment: Try escaping special chars with https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/3832970

Comment: @Melbfella why are you  `'some text :('
strRegEx = emoticon.SymbolShortcut.replace(')', '[)]').replace('(', '[(]');` doing this ?

Answer (score -1):

**Updated The answer while keeping OP's flow into consideration:**

```js
var pText ='some text :('

strRegEx = `:(`.replace(')', '\\)').replace('(', '\\(');
var regEx = new RegExp(strRegEx, "i");
pText = pText.replace(regEx,`<i class="material-icons emoticon" style="font-size:16x;">sentiment_very_satisfied</i>`);
console.log(pText);
```

Comment: I guess the downvote is for not explaining the working of the regex, but the answer seems pretty clear to me.